# How can I display the newly updated variable currentPaginationData from the updateRowsPerPage function?

Tags: reactjs

```html
import BlogPost from "./BlogPost";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import React from "react";
import blogs from "../data/blogs.json";

const PAGE_SIZES = [15, 25, 50, 100];

function BlogList() {
  let currentPaginationData = blogs.posts.slice(0, 15);

  const updateRowsPerPage = (numPerPage) => {
    currentPaginationData = blogs.posts.slice(0, numPerPage);
    console.log(currentPaginationData);
  };
  
   const updatePage = () => {};

  return (
    <div>
      <Pagination
        currentPage={1}
        totalCount={blogs.posts.length}
        pageSize={15}
        pageSizeOptions={PAGE_SIZES}
        onPageChange={updatePage}
        onPageSizeOptionChange={updateRowsPerPage}
      />
      <ul
        // Do not remove the aria-label below, it is used for Hatchways automation.
        aria-label="blog list"
      >
        {currentPaginationData.map((blog) => (
          <BlogPost
            key={blog.id}
            author={blog.author}
            title={blog.title}
            excerpt={blog.excerpt}
            featureImage={blog.image}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlogList;
```

This jsx file will display the first 15 users blogs on start up and my updateRowsPerPage function updates the currentPaginationData successfully. I checked with the console.log statement. However, my DOM doesn't seem to be updating and showing the new updated value assigned to currentPaginationData and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need To Store the Current Pagination Data in the State Variable and Update it with the SetState in the Update Rows Per Page..

```
const [currentPaginationData,setCurrentPaginationData] = useState(blogs.posts.slice(0, 15))

const updateRowsPerPage = (numPerPage) => {
    let data = blogs.posts.slice(0, numPerPage);
    setCurrentPaginationData(data)
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked when I entered it into my function. I tried that but instead of using the variable data. I used setCurrentPaginationData and set that equal to  blogs.posts.slice(0, numPerPage). Could you explain why that doesn't work?

Comment: In React, If you directly update the value of the variable it does not rerender the Ui.. So We Use UseStateHook..   https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html                                                https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-every-react-developer-should-know-about-state/